# Guardar en variables los valores de una fila al dar doble clic en una celda (vb.net) (visual studio) (datagrid)

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, datagrid, vb, microsoft

actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación.
Cargo un BD a un datagrid, pero quiero que cuando le den clic en algun lugar de una celda, se almacenen todos los strings de cada celda-columna en variables.
¿cómo lo puedo hacer?

se que e en el evento de _CellContentDoubleClick pero no se como almacenar los datos en variables de la celda en la fila que corresponde

Ejemplo...
[image: Gri1]

al dar clic en 14 que en una variable me guarde c, en otra 3, en otra r, en otra 14 y en la ultima User3

```
Private Sub ProductInformation_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles ProductInformation.CellContentDoubleClick


    Dim strValor As String = ""


    strValor = ProductInformation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value
    MsgBox(strValor)

End Sub
```

Comment: Si agregas el codigo que tienes hasta el momento los usuarios te podran ayudar mejor!

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que cambiar el index o el nombre de la columna de la que quieres obtener los datos.

```
Private Sub ProductInformation_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles ProductInformation.CellContentDoubleClick


    Dim strValor0 As String = ""
    Dim strValor1 As String = ""
    Dim strValor2 As String = ""


    strValor0 = ProductInformation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
    strValor1 = ProductInformation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value
    strValor2 = ProductInformation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value

    MsgBox(strValor0 + " " + strValor1 + " " strValor2)
End Sub
```

En caso de que vayas a usar las variables en otra parte del código, declaralas afuera de tu método.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto.
Si era eso, cambiar el index para ver los datos de la fila!